# How do i pass Multiple values in a single header during parameterization in soap ui

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui, parameterized

I need to obtain multiple values from a json response and pass those values as a parameter in the header of the next request test step.

Say like I got the response as below:

```
{
   "access_token": "tokenvalue",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "expires_in": 7200,
   "refresh_token": ""
}
```

Now I need to get the values of `token_type` and `accesstoken` and  pass it as header key 'Authorization' and value as `"bearer tokenvalue"` to next test step.

Please let me know how to do the same.

Comment: Can you please add the raw response of previous step and next step request as well?

Comment: Hi Rao,

This is the reponse of previous step
{ "access_token": "245634534rggdfg", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 7200, "refresh_token": "34534wrgg4g4g" }

Now i need to pass the token_type and access_token in an header called "Authorization" as "token_type+access_token" of the next request. I need to pass both the values over there.

Comment: You mean to say, extract `access_token` and `tokeen_type` from previous response and send them in the header of next step? what is the name of the header?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using groovy script as well

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap 


responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Name of the test   step token is included in the responce ").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)

access_tok = slurperresponse.data.token
```

//set parameter values for the next request

```
def headers = new StringToStringMap()
headers.put("x-auth-token",access_tok)
headers.put("Content-Type","application/json")
headers.put("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest")
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Name of the test step which need to set the header section with access   token").testRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Add a **script assertion** to the first test step with the below code(the one where you get the access token and token type).

> **Note:** Provide the appropriate value in the script for **nextStepName, headerName** variables if they differ from your values. Currently values set are **REST Test Request, Authorization** respectively. You may ignore editing if you have the same values.

```groovy
/**
* below is script assertion for the first step and 
* will set http headers to the given test step with in 
* the same test case user need to pass the test step name, 
* and header name if any change
**/

//Modify the name of the test step as needed in your case
def nextStepName = 'REST Test Request'
def headerName = 'Authorization'

//Do not require to edit beyond this
def setHttpHeaders(String stepName, def headers) {
    def nextRequest = context.testCase.testSteps[stepName].httpRequest
    def existingHeaders = nextRequest.requestHeaders
    headers.each {
        existingHeaders[it.key] = it.value
    }
    nextRequest.requestHeaders = existingHeaders
}
def jsonResponse = new net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.response.contentAsString)
assert jsonResponse.access_token, "Access token is empty or null"
assert jsonResponse.token_type, "Token type is empty or null"
//creating the header value separated by space between the two
String headerValue =  "${jsonResponse.token_type} ${jsonResponse.access_token}"
def headers = [(headerName) : [(headerValue)]]
setHttpHeaders(nextStepName, headers)
```

Comment: HI Rao,
 Thanks for the response.. Is there any other way to concatenate the both the values and pass it in the header other than the groovy scripting?

Comment: I would appreciate you can tell - what did you find when you run the above resolution?

Comment: You did not even mention in the question that what is your preferred way of doing the same? Hope you at least tried it!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple procedure that can be accomplished with absolutely no scripting.

In your resource, where you need the header parameters, create a header parameter called "Authorization". Official [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html#1-4-HEADER-parameters) on creating header parameters is available.

To transfer the data, for the value use a simple parameter expansion: `${previous_step_name#ResponseAsXml#//*:token_type}+${previous_step_name#ResponseAsXml#//*:access_token}`. Additional [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html) on transferring parameters is available.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it using java.
here is example code.

```
String name = "username";
            String password = "Simple4u!";
            String authString = name + ":" + password;
            String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
            System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(
                "http://localhost:8080/rest123/rest/message/abc?param=Hello");
        request.accept("text/plain").header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        ClientResponse<String> response = request.get(String.class);
```

then those username and password mapped with @HeaderParam automatically
Hope this will help you !!!